# Проблемы с django-robokassa

Tags: django, платежи

Пытаюсь внедрить django-robokassa в свой проект. При python manage.py migrate выдает ошибку

```
    ImportError: No module named south.db
```

Версия Django 1.9.5, не использую South. Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложение django-robokassa использует South migration, а не Django migration. Если вы не используете South, то попробуйте просто:`python manage.py syncdb`

Также у robokassa сменился URL отправки формы, поменяйте в conf.py на:
`FORM_TARGET = u'https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/Index.aspx'`

Comment: Django 1.9 не использует syncdb, вместо него сейчас используют migrate. Поменяли в Django 1.8 версии

Comment: Сделайте тогда migrations для django-robokassa: `python manage.py makemigrations django-robokassa`, а затем migrate.
Возможно придется предварительно удалить каталог migrations, который для south.

Comment: Всё заработало спасибо!

Comment: betonimig еще вопрос. Шаблоны не работают. То есть когда делаю запрос на робокассу, я перехожу в тестовый сервер, после когда выбираю прошла успешно или не прошла, то робокасса перенаправляет на мой сайт, /robokassa/success/ который должен вернуть html страницу success.html или error.html. Но этих шаблонов нету в проекте django - robokassa. Что делать?

Comment: Создайте свои. Добавьте каталог robokassa в templates, а в него fail.html и success.html.  
Пример файла success.html:`{% extends 'base.html' %}{% block content %}Оплата прошла успешно!{% endblock %}`

Comment: betonimig то есть создать внутри самого django-robokassa или у себя и как то привязать их?

Comment: всё заработало! спасибо

Comment: Можете хоть в приложении django-robokassa создать каталог templates/robokassa, хоть у себя в проекте, в каталог templates добавить robokassa. Джанго его найдет.